# swift string comparison not working as expected

Tags: swift

```
print(itemToRefresh)
print(cell.item!.id)

if (itemToRefresh == cell.item!.id) {
    print("MATCHED")
}
```

Output:

```
Optional("PI096")
Optional("PI096")
```

"Matched" does not get printed.  Why?

Comment: Is the datatype itemToRefresh and cell.item!.id is same?

Answer (score 0):

itemToRefresh was a string, but it turns out that earlier in my code I had assigned it like so:

let itemToRefresh = "\(foo)"

should have been

let itemToRefresh = "\(foo!)"

Answer (score 0):

it should have been let itemToRefresh = "(foo!)" for e.g

```
let foo: String? = "ABC"

let itemToRefresh = "\(foo!)" // will be -> ABC
// let itemToRefresh = "\(foo)" // will be -> optional(ABC)
// and optional(ABC) will not be equal to ABC

let itemb = "ABC"

print(itemToRefresh) // ABC
print(itemb)        // ABC

if itemToRefresh == itemb {   // true
  print("123") // print 123
}
```

if you want you can safely unwrap optional value and check

```
if (foo != nil) {

  let itemToRefresh = "\(foo!)" // will be -> ABC
  // let itemToRefresh = "\(foo)" // will be -> "optional(ABC)"

  let itemb = "ABC"

  print(itemToRefresh)
  print(itemb)

  if itemToRefresh == itemb {
    print("123")
  }
}
```